# ViewController.xib is not opening

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS developments. I started with a basic app described in  [this tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-development-tutorial-series-hello-world/). According to that I have to open ViewController.xib in order to create an interface. But that particular file is not opened within Xcode. What can I do to open that file or is there any alternative method (manually) to create interfaces?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: In your project viewController.xib is missing or what?

Comment: According to tutorials once we double click on the .xib file we will be able to drag and drop components. But in my case that dragging and dropping facilities are not opened. It simply does not do anything when I double click on the .xib file

Comment: Delete your project and try again.

Comment: I did it, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using xcode3.2, the xib will not be opened on Xcode rather it will be in **Interface Builder.**

Comment: No Interface Builder is a sub-part of XCode, these both gets installed  when you install XCode. Check your system if Interface Builder is there or not.